# Module that executes a sequence of actions in any possible order

Tags: haskell, monads

Below is a module that executes a sequence of actions in any possible order.  `LANGUAGE_DataKinds` and `LANGUAGE_DefaultSignatures` are predefined cpp symbols.

Is this permutation applicative/monad implementation clear?  I am particularly concerned about the use of DataKinds and GADTs, and if I should instead split it in to two separate implementations (one for Applicative/Alternative, one for Monad/MonadPlus).

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#ifdef LANGUAGE_DataKinds
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
#else
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
#endif
{-# LANGUAGE
    FlexibleInstances
  , GADTs
  , MultiParamTypeClasses
  , Rank2Types
  , TypeSynonymInstances
  , UndecidableInstances #-}
{- |
Stability: experimental
Portability: non-portable
-}
module Control.Monad.Perm.Internal
       ( Perm
       , runPerm
       , PermT
       , runPermT
       , PermC
       , liftPerm
       , hoistPerm
       ) where

import Control.Applicative hiding (Applicative)
import qualified Control.Applicative as Applicative (Applicative)
import Control.Monad hiding (Monad)
import qualified Control.Monad as Monad (Monad)
import Control.Monad.Catch.Class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Control.Monad.State.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (MonadTrans (lift))

import Data.Foldable (foldr)
import Data.Monoid ((<>), mempty)

import Prelude (Maybe (..), ($), (.), const, flip, fst, id, map, maybe)

-- | The permutation applicative
type Perm = PermC Applicative

-- | The permutation monad
type PermT = PermC Monad

{- |
The permutation action, available as either an 'Applicative.Applicative'
or a 'Monad.Monad', determined by the combinators used.
-}
data PermC c m a = Choice (Maybe a) [Branch c m a]

data Branch c m b where
  Ap :: PermC c m (a -> b) -> m a -> Branch c m b
  Bind :: (a -> PermT m b) -> m a -> Branch Monad m b

#ifdef LANGUAGE_DataKinds
data Constraint = Applicative | Monad
#else
data Applicative
data Monad
#endif

instance Functor (PermC c m) where
  fmap f (Choice a xs) = Choice (f <$> a) (fmap f <$> xs)

instance Functor (Branch c m) where
  fmap f (Ap perm m) = Ap (fmap (f .) perm) m
  fmap f (Bind k m) = Bind (fmap f . k) m

instance Applicative.Applicative (PermC c m) where
  pure a = Choice (pure a) mempty
  f@(Choice f' fs) <*> a@(Choice a' as) =
    Choice (f' <*> a') (fmap (`apB` a) fs <> fmap (f `apP`) as)
  (*>) = liftThen (*>)

apP :: PermC c m (a -> b) -> Branch c m a -> Branch c m b
f `apP` Ap perm m = (f .@ perm) `Ap` m
f `apP` Bind k m = Bind ((f `ap`) . k) m

(.@) :: Applicative.Applicative f => f (b -> c) -> f (a -> b) -> f (a -> c)
(.@) = liftA2 (.)

apB :: Branch c m (a -> b) -> PermC c m a -> Branch c m b
Ap perm m `apB` a = flipA2 perm a `Ap` m
Bind k m `apB` a = Bind ((`ap` a) . k) m

flipA2 :: Applicative.Applicative f => f (a -> b -> c) -> f b -> f (a -> c)
flipA2 = liftA2 flip

instance Alternative (PermC c m) where
  empty = liftZero empty
  (<|>) = plus

instance Monad.Monad (PermT m) where
  return a = Choice (return a) mempty
  Choice Nothing xs >>= k = Choice Nothing (map (bindP k) xs)
  Choice (Just a) xs >>= k = case k a of
    Choice a' xs' -> Choice a' (map (bindP k) xs <> xs')
  (>>) = liftThen (>>)
  fail _ = Choice mzero mempty

bindP :: (a -> PermT m b) -> Branch Monad m a -> Branch Monad m b
bindP k (Ap perm m) = Bind (\ a -> k . ($ a) =<< perm) m
bindP k (Bind k' m) = Bind (k <=< k') m

instance MonadPlus (PermT m) where
  mzero = liftZero mzero
  mplus = plus

instance MonadTrans (PermC c) where
  lift = liftPerm

instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (PermT m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO

instance MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (PermT m) where
  ask = lift ask
  local f (Choice a xs) = Choice a (map (localBranch f) xs)

localBranch :: MonadReader r m =>
               (r -> r) -> Branch Monad m a -> Branch Monad m a
localBranch f (Ap perm m) = Ap (local f perm) (local f m)
localBranch f (Bind k m) = Bind (local f . k) (local f m)

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (PermT m) where
  get = lift get
  put = lift . put

#ifdef LANGUAGE_DefaultSignatures
instance MonadThrow e m => MonadThrow e (PermT m)
#else
instance MonadThrow e m => MonadThrow e (PermT m) where
  throw = lift . throw
#endif

liftThen :: (Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe b) ->
            PermC c m a -> PermC c m b -> PermC c m b
liftThen thenMaybe m@(Choice m' ms) n@(Choice n' ns) =
  Choice (m' `thenMaybe` n') (map (`thenB` n) ms <> map (m `thenP`) ns)

thenP :: PermC c m a -> Branch c m b -> Branch c m b
m `thenP` Ap perm m' = (m *> perm) `Ap` m'
m `thenP` Bind k m' = Bind ((m >>) . k) m'

thenB :: Branch c m a -> PermC c m b -> Branch c m b
Ap perm m `thenB` n = (perm *> fmap const n) `Ap` m
Bind k m `thenB` n = Bind ((>> n) . k) m

liftZero :: Maybe a -> PermC c m a
liftZero zeroMaybe = Choice zeroMaybe mempty

plus :: PermC c m a -> PermC c m a -> PermC c m a
m@(Choice (Just _) _) `plus` _ = m
Choice Nothing xs `plus` Choice b ys = Choice b (xs <> ys)

-- | Unwrap a 'Perm', combining actions using the 'Alternative' for @f@.
runPerm :: Alternative m => Perm m a -> m a
runPerm = lower
  where
    lower (Choice a xs) = foldr ((<|>) . f) (maybe empty pure a) xs
    f (perm `Ap` m) = m <**> runPerm perm

-- | Unwrap a 'PermC', combining actions using the 'MonadPlus' for @f@.
runPermT :: MonadPlus m => PermT m a -> m a
runPermT = lower
  where
    lower (Choice a xs) = foldr (mplus . f) (maybe mzero return a) xs
    f (perm `Ap` m) = flip ($) `liftM` m `ap` runPermT perm
    f (Bind k m) = m >>= runPermT . k

-- | A version of 'lift' without the @'Monad.Monad' m@ constraint
liftPerm :: m a -> PermC c m a
liftPerm = Choice empty . pure . liftBranch

liftBranch :: m a -> Branch c m a
liftBranch = Ap (Choice (pure id) mempty)

{- |
Lift a natural transformation from @m@ to @n@ into a natural transformation
from @'PermC' c m@ to @'PermC' c n@.
-}
hoistPerm :: (forall a . m a -> n a) -> PermC c m b -> PermC c n b
hoistPerm f (Choice a xs) = Choice a (hoistBranch f <$> xs)

hoistBranch :: (forall a . m a -> n a) -> Branch c m b -> Branch c n b
hoistBranch f (perm `Ap` m) = hoistPerm f perm `Ap` f m
hoistBranch f (Bind k m) = Bind (hoistPerm f . k) (f m)
```

Comment: Can you add a usage example?

Comment: Yes, some example, and perhaps describing how this monad works, would be helpful.

Comment: With parsec: `runPermT $ lift (char 'a') *> lift (char 'b')` should match `"ab"` or `"bc"` and always return `'b'`.  The same should happen if `>>` is used instead of `*>`, as well as if `liftPerm` is used instead of `lift`, assuming the underlying monad's `Applicative` and `Monad` instances are coherent.

Answer (score 3):

As `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` are both monoids `foldMap` seems more appropriate than `foldr`. Note that you need to define the instances using newtypes. Fortunately these instances are defined in `reducers` package. So:

```
foldMonadPlus2 f x = getMonadSum $ foldMap (MonadSum . f) x
foldAlternative2 f x = getAlternate $ foldMap (Alternate . f) x
```

It doesn't look very nice, but you can use `newtype` package to make it better:

```
foldMonadPlus3 f x = ala (MonadSum . f) foldMap x
foldAlternate3 f x = ala (Alternate . f) foldMap x
```

Unfortunately you have to define two instances so it's not any shorter:

```
instance MonadPlus m => Newtype (MonadSum m a) (m a) where
    pack = MonadSum
    unpack = getMonadSum

instance Alternative m => Newtype (Alternate m a) (m a) where
    pack = Alternate
    unpack = getAlternate
```

Maybe someone else could exploit this idea further.

Another approach is to use `msum` and `asum`:

```
foldMonadPlus f x = asum $ fmap f x
foldAlternative f x = msum $ fmap f x
```

You then can define

```
lower (Choice a xs) = foldMonadPlus f xs `mplus` (maybe mzero return a)
```

And similar for `Applicative`. Note that `x` is not any `Foldable` but always a list so you may want just to import `foldr` from `Prelude` instead.

I use the following code to test:

```
let a x = Perm2.liftPerm (print x) in runPermT (a 0 >> a 0 >> a 1 >> mzero)
```

Couldn't invent anything similar for `Applicative`.

I could extract common code from `runPerm` and `runPermT`:

```
prepare g f (Choice a xs) = maybe id ((:) . g) a $ map f xs
```

The functions look identical, just `lower` is respectively:

```
lower = asum . prepare pure f
lower = msum . prepare return f
```

Import of `Data.Monoid` can be removed without a loss of genericity as only the list monoid is actually used. So all `<>` can be replaced with `++` and `mempty` with `[]`. Are there any other `Foldable a, Monoid a` types useful to store branches besides lists?

I think it is a good idea to try to extract a recursor for `Choice` and write everything else non-recursively if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I have now.  For modifications to this solution, please add a new answer that I can choose (rather than comment on it).  Disadvantages compared to the original implementation include an additional `Monad n` constraint on `hoistPerm`.  Advantages include a simpler exposed data type (no odd phantom type parameter) and the removal of the dubious use of `DataKinds`.  I am still very open to advice, and will leave the question open.  Of particular concern now is how `runPermT` does not use `Applicative m`, but instead relies on the equivalent `Monad` operations - should `Ap` be changed to include a local `Applicative m` constraint?  Doing so would add another constraint to `hoistPerm` of `Applicative n` - which though trivially satisfied, is still kind of odd.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    CPP
  , FlexibleInstances
  , GADTs
  , MultiParamTypeClasses
  , Rank2Types
  , UndecidableInstances #-}
{- |
Stability: experimental
Portability: non-portable
-}
module Control.Monad.Perm.Internal
       ( Perm
       , runPerm
       , PermT
       , runPermT
       , liftPerm
       , hoistPerm
       ) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Catch.Class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Control.Monad.State.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (MonadTrans (lift))

import Data.Foldable (foldr)
import Data.Monoid (mempty)
#if defined(__GLASGOW_HASKELL__) && __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 704
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
#else
import Data.Monoid (Monoid, mappend)
#endif

import Prelude (Maybe (..), ($), (.), const, flip, fst, id, map, maybe)

#if !defined(__GLASGOW_HASKELL__) || __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ < 704
(<>) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m
(<>) = mappend
{-# INLINE (<>) #-}
#endif

-- | The permutation applicative
type Perm = PermT

-- | The permutation monad
data PermT m a = Choice (Maybe a) [Branch m a]

data Branch m b where
  Ap :: PermT m (a -> b) -> m a -> Branch m b
  Bind :: Monad m => (a -> PermT m b) -> m a -> Branch m b

instance Functor (PermT m) where
  fmap f (Choice a xs) = Choice (f <$> a) (fmap f <$> xs)

instance Functor (Branch m) where
  fmap f (Ap perm m) = Ap (fmap (f .) perm) m
  fmap f (Bind k m) = Bind (fmap f . k) m

instance Applicative (PermT m) where
  pure a = Choice (pure a) mempty
  f@(Choice f' fs) <*> a@(Choice a' as) =
    Choice (f' <*> a') (fmap (`apB` a) fs <> fmap (f `apP`) as)
  (*>) = liftThen (*>)

apP :: PermT m (a -> b) -> Branch m a -> Branch m b
f `apP` Ap perm m = (f .@ perm) `Ap` m
f `apP` Bind k m = Bind ((f `ap`) . k) m

(.@) :: Applicative f => f (b -> c) -> f (a -> b) -> f (a -> c)
(.@) = liftA2 (.)

apB :: Branch m (a -> b) -> PermT m a -> Branch m b
Ap perm m `apB` a = flipA2 perm a `Ap` m
Bind k m `apB` a = Bind ((`ap` a) . k) m

flipA2 :: Applicative f => f (a -> b -> c) -> f b -> f (a -> c)
flipA2 = liftA2 flip

instance Alternative (PermT m) where
  empty = liftZero empty
  (<|>) = plus

instance Monad m => Monad (PermT m) where
  return a = Choice (return a) mempty
  Choice Nothing xs >>= k = Choice Nothing (map (bindP k) xs)
  Choice (Just a) xs >>= k = case k a of
    Choice a' xs' -> Choice a' (map (bindP k) xs <> xs')
  (>>) = liftThen (>>)
  fail _ = Choice mzero mempty

bindP :: Monad m => (a -> PermT m b) -> Branch m a -> Branch m b
bindP k (Ap perm m) = Bind (\ a -> k . ($ a) =<< perm) m
bindP k (Bind k' m) = Bind (k <=< k') m

instance Monad m => MonadPlus (PermT m) where
  mzero = liftZero mzero
  mplus = plus

instance MonadTrans PermT where
  lift = liftPerm

instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (PermT m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO

instance MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (PermT m) where
  ask = lift ask
  local f (Choice a xs) = Choice a (map (localBranch f) xs)

localBranch :: MonadReader r m => (r -> r) -> Branch m a -> Branch m a
localBranch f (Ap perm m) = Ap (local f perm) (local f m)
localBranch f (Bind k m) = Bind (local f . k) (local f m)

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (PermT m) where
  get = lift get
  put = lift . put

#ifdef LANGUAGE_DefaultSignatures
instance MonadThrow e m => MonadThrow e (PermT m)
#else
instance MonadThrow e m => MonadThrow e (PermT m) where
  throw = lift . throw
#endif

liftThen :: (Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe b) ->
            PermT m a -> PermT m b -> PermT m b
liftThen thenMaybe m@(Choice m' ms) n@(Choice n' ns) =
  Choice (m' `thenMaybe` n') (map (`thenB` n) ms <> map (m `thenP`) ns)

thenP :: PermT m a -> Branch m b -> Branch m b
m `thenP` Ap perm m' = (m *> perm) `Ap` m'
m `thenP` Bind k m' = Bind ((m >>) . k) m'

thenB :: Branch m a -> PermT m b -> Branch m b
Ap perm m `thenB` n = (perm *> fmap const n) `Ap` m
Bind k m `thenB` n = Bind ((>> n) . k) m

liftZero :: Maybe a -> PermT m a
liftZero zeroMaybe = Choice zeroMaybe mempty

plus :: PermT m a -> PermT m a -> PermT m a
m@(Choice (Just _) _) `plus` _ = m
Choice Nothing xs `plus` Choice b ys = Choice b (xs <> ys)

-- | Unwrap a 'Perm', combining actions using the 'Alternative' for @f@.
runPerm :: Alternative m => Perm m a -> m a
runPerm = lower
  where
    lower (Choice a xs) = foldr ((<|>) . f) (maybe empty pure a) xs
    f (perm `Ap` m) = m <**> runPerm perm
    f (Bind k m) = m >>= runPerm . k

-- | Unwrap a 'PermT', combining actions using the 'MonadPlus' for @f@.
runPermT :: MonadPlus m => PermT m a -> m a
runPermT = lower
  where
    lower (Choice a xs) = foldr (mplus . f) (maybe mzero return a) xs
    f (perm `Ap` m) = flip ($) `liftM` m `ap` runPermT perm
    f (Bind k m) = m >>= runPermT . k

-- | A version of 'lift' without the @'Monad.Monad' m@ constraint
liftPerm :: m a -> PermT m a
liftPerm = Choice empty . pure . liftBranch

liftBranch :: m a -> Branch m a
liftBranch = Ap (Choice (pure id) mempty)

{- |
Lift a natural transformation from @m@ to @n@ into a natural transformation
from @'PermT'' c m@ to @'PermT'' c n@.
-}
hoistPerm :: Monad n => (forall a . m a -> n a) -> PermT m b -> PermT n b
hoistPerm f (Choice a xs) = Choice a (hoistBranch f <$> xs)

hoistBranch :: Monad n => (forall a . m a -> n a) -> Branch m b -> Branch n b
hoistBranch f (perm `Ap` m) = hoistPerm f perm `Ap` f m
hoistBranch f (Bind k m) = Bind (hoistPerm f . k) (f m)
```